# Получить область модификации (обновляемый регион заданного окна)

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

Возможно ли как-то в потомке TWinControl-а в обработке WM_PAINT получить область модификации (обновляемый регион заданного окна)?

Пробовал вызывать функцию GetUpdateRect, но в TWinControl.PaintHandler к этому моменту уже происходит вызов BeginPaint и область модификации валидируется, поэтому GetUpdateRect возвращает пустой прямоугольник.
А перменная типа TPaintStruct является локальной для TWinControl.PaintHandler и доступа к ней нет.

Comment: просто объявите обработчик WM_PAINT (с вызовом inherited *после* своих манипуляций с GetUpdateRect)

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы включить свой обработчик любого сообщения Windows (помимо "штатного", имеющегося в исходниках VCL), необходимо просто объявить его. Например, так:

```
TmyForm = class(TForm)
private
  procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
...
```

Главное - не забыть вызвать штатный обработчик через Inherited. В вашем случае действительно вызывать штатный нужно после выполнения своего кода, т.к. в противном случае обновляемый регион вы не сможете получить:

```
procedure TmyForm.WMPaint(var Message: TMessage); message WM_Paint;
begin
  // вызываем GetUpdateRect, проводим дополнительные манипуляции
  inherited; // штатный обработчик
  // Здесь тоже можно проводить манипуляции, но GetUpdateRect уже вернет "пусто".
end;
```